# Can submodule A be the submodule of project B & C, when B is also the submodule of C?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have 3 projects. The main project (called Main) has two submodules : Config & Core.

Core also has a submodule which is also "Config".

Is that imposslbe, ill-advised, or "okay if change some settings first" ?

Comment: At the *Git* level, it's fine. Main/Config is the submodule named Config in Main, and Main/Core/Config is the submodule named Config in Main/Core. Whether there are conflicts between the two copies of "Config" is another (non-Git) question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is when you are doing changed in `Main/Config`: you need to push those modification from `Main/Config` (and commit in Main), then possibly update Core in order to get the latest from `Core/Config`.

That can become complex to manage.

A possible workaround would be to symlink `Main/Config` to `Main/Core/Config`, and only modify `Config` from `Main/Core/Config`.